# Custom component object/property is not persisting

Tags: sitecore-commerce

When I have the custom components below one object/property is not persisting. The list component is really just a container to hold a collection of ChildComponents of type AdjustmentExtendedComponent. When I add AdjustmentExtendedListComponent to a cart line on an Order and persist the order everything saves to the database except the  AwardedAdjustment property. Is it completely missing from the json in the database.

```
using Sitecore.Commerce.Core;

namespace MyClient.Commerce.Plugin.Pricing.Components
{
    public class AdjustmentExtendedListComponent : Component
    {

    }
}

using MyClient.Commerce.Shared.Enums;
using Sitecore.Commerce.Core;
using Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.Pricing;
using Sitecore.Framework.Conditions;

namespace MyClient.Commerce.Plugin.Pricing.Components
{
    public class AdjustmentExtendedComponent : Component
    {
        // used in Azure after deserialize
        public string AdjustmentType { get; set; }

        public AwardedAdjustment AssociatedAdjustment { get; }

        public DiscountCode DiscountCode { get; }

        public decimal AdjustmentRate { get; }

        public string TaxExemptReasonCode { get; set; }

        public AdjustmentExtendedComponent()
        {
        }

        public AdjustmentExtendedComponent(AwardedAdjustment associatedAdjustment, decimal adjustmentRate)
        {
            Condition.Requires(associatedAdjustment, nameof(associatedAdjustment)).IsNotNull();

            AssociatedAdjustment = associatedAdjustment;

            AdjustmentRate = adjustmentRate;

            AdjustmentType = ((AwardedAdjustment)associatedAdjustment)?.AdjustmentType;
        }

        public AdjustmentExtendedComponent(AwardedAdjustment associatedAdjustment, DiscountCode discountCode)
        {
            Condition.Requires(associatedAdjustment, nameof(associatedAdjustment)).IsNotNull();

            AssociatedAdjustment = associatedAdjustment;

            DiscountCode = discountCode;

            AdjustmentType = ((AwardedAdjustment)associatedAdjustment)?.AdjustmentType;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - my eye's betrayed me!

Answer (score 2):

You must add setters to your properties, like:

```
public AwardedAdjustment AssociatedAdjustment { get; set; }

public DiscountCode DiscountCode { get; set; }

public decimal AdjustmentRate { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what inside in `AwardedAdjustment` class, but you can try below things:

```
    //apply setter in your property
    public AwardedAdjustment AssociatedAdjustment { get; set; }

    //Constructor 
    public AdjustmentExtendedComponent()
    {
         //initialize here
         AssociatedAdjustment = new AwardedAdjustment(); 
    }
```

Hope it will fix your issue.